# Unit testing endpoints which use MySQL and TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, typeorm

I´m unit testing my node.js backend application for the first time, so I have an issue with the endpoints that use entities from TypeORM. The testing libraries I´m using are **jest**, **supertest**, **@databases/mysql-test** and **typeorm**

*@databases/mysql-test* is for creating a MySQL container for the tests, so I specified it in the jest.config.file as the next way:

```
@type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} */
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/",
    "./gitignore",
    "./Dockerfile",
  ],
  setupFiles: [
    './tests/setupTests.ts'
  ],
  globalSetup: "C:/project_path/backend/node_modules/@databases/mysql-test/jest/globalSetup",
  globalTeardown: "C:/project_path/backend/node_modules/@databases/mysql-test/jest/globalTeardown",
};
```

The next code (testhelper.ts) is the class where I try to connect to MySQL:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../src/entities/User';
import { Chat } from '../src/entities/Chat';
import { Language } from "../src/entities/Language"; 
import 'dotenv/config';

// Singleton class
export class TestHelper {

  private static _instance: TestHelper;
  private dbConnect!: DataSource;

  private constructor(){}

  public static get instance(): TestHelper {
    if(!this._instance) this._instance = new TestHelper();

    return this._instance;
  }

  public async setupDB() {
    this.dbConnect = new DataSource({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3307,
      username: 'root',
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
      entities: [User, Chat, Language], // tables
      synchronize: true,
    });
    this.dbConnect.initialize();
  }

  public async teardownTestDB() {
    this.dbConnect.destroy();
  }

}
```

And in the next code are the test (chat.test.ts):

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../src/app';
import { TestHelper } from './testhelper'
beforeAll(async () => {
  console.log(process.env.DB_PASSWORD);
  TestHelper.instance.setupDB();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  TestHelper.instance.teardownTestDB();
});

// success
describe('POST /chat/message_array', () => {
  test('Return an audio file', async () => {
    const response = await request(app)
                            .post('/chat/message_array')
                            .send({
                              payload: [
                                {role: "system", content: "Your are a helpful chatbot"},
                                {role: "user", content: "Who are you?" }
                              ],
                              language: "english",
                              gender: "male"
                            });
                            
    expect(response.statusCode).toBe(200);
    expect(response.header['content-type']).toBe('audio/mp3');
    expect(response.header['content-disposition']).toBe('attachment; filename=speech_uuid.mp3');
    expect(response.body instanceof Buffer).toBeTruthy();
  }, 20_000);
});
```

The problem comes when I run the tests, I got this:

```
C:\project_path\node_modules\typeorm\data-source\DataSource.js:180
            throw new error_1.CannotExecuteNotConnectedError(this.name);
                  ^
CannotExecuteNotConnectedError: Cannot execute operation on "default" connection because connection is not yet established.
```

I tried to add jest.useFakeTimers() in both files but it couldn't change the error.